# HTML attributes aren't being highlighted in vscode?

Tags: syntax, themes, editor, settings, visual-studio-code

I'm seeing really boring HTML formatting in vscode. I just spent like 3 hours trying to figure out what was going on, and I can't find any solution or fix. Hoping someone knows why my HTML formatting looks uninteresting, or any ideas to change it, and I think it might be a bug.

[image]

I'm not sure why, but the attributes aren't being nicely highlighted. I'd love some sort of suggestion to fix this!

PS: React JSX works fine:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My apologies. Seems this is an issue with the Tomorrow theme; in general, I have found that every `Tomorrow` variant has this issue.